# Block Android 6 upgrade?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

I am getting pushes for Android 6 Marshmallow on a couple devices.  I do not want or need it, especially with some changes that affect how the USB popup now has no "Just Once" option in 6.x (according to other reports).

So, without rooting them, is there a way to block/disable/remove the upgrade pending notification push "Software update ready to install".  Frankly I didn't want it to download it in the first place.  I am perfectly happy with Lollipop on them the way they are and I need the "Just Once" option with what I do with them via USB.

Now frequently when I unlock my phone (Galaxy S5) it pops up full screen and only option is "Now" or "Later".  There is no "Never" option.

On my tablet (nVidia Shield K1), it pops up every time I turn it on.

Any way to clear this upgrade sans root?  I guess if I have to root to get rid of this update, I will.  If thats the only option, I can figure out how to root the devices.  Past that anyone have instructions on the upgrade removal once rooted?

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  The other Q about the update did not solve the problem.  I looked at the various answers there and none applied or worked.  Unchecking what was described in that other thread still results in the popup.  The other thread's answer did not solve the issue or I wouldn't have posted this specific to the S5 and Shield K1.

Comment: Since it appears the OTC is unblockable without rooting.  Its rooted.  Problem solved.